# I want one array to display the value of the other array when looped through

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I created a table in HTML, with one row and three columns. These are `sumName`, `sumEmail` & `sumCard`. I would like to get the text value from another table, with the ID's of `commentNameA`, `commentEmailA` & `commentCardA` and have them transfer accordingly to the sum ID's.

I have tried using different functions however i can't find the right solution.

Java Script:

```
function summary() {

    var sumShow = [name, email, card];
    var position = [posName, posEmail, posCard];

    var name = document.getElementById("commentNameA").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("commentEmailA").value;
    var card = document.getElementById("commentCardA").value;
    var posName = document.getElementById("sumName").innerHTML;
    var posEmail = document.getElementById("sumEmail").innerHTML;
    var posCard = document.getElementById("sumCard").innerHTML;



    for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
        var k = 0;
        position[i] = sumShow[k];
        k += 1;
        }

    }
```

HTML:

```
<form action=" " method=" " >
    <table id = "order">

      <tr>
        <td id = "commentName">Name:<input type="text" name="Name" id="commentNameA" class="name" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" onkeyup="validateName()" ></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="commentEmail">Email:<input type="email" name="Email" id="commentEmailA" onkeyup="validateEmail()" class="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id ="commentCard">Card:<input type="text" name="Card_Number" id="commentCardA" class="card" onkeyup="update(this.value)" placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number" ></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="commentButton"><button id="commentForm" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" >Submit Form</button></td>
      </tr>
   </table>
  </form> 

<div id="sumTable" class="summary">
    <table id="sumTableA" class="summaryTable" style="width:100%" >
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th> 
    <th>Card Number</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="sumName"> </td>
    <td id="sumEmail"> </td> 
    <td id="sumCard"> </td>
  </tr>
    <input id="sumBtn" onclick="summary()" type="submit" name="summary" class="sumBtn" value="summary" />
    </table>

</div>
```

There are no errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E.g. `posName` ist storing the innerHTML as a string and not a reference to this attribute in the DOM. so when you cange `position[i] = sumShow[k];`, you are not modifying the DOM but just changing the string inside the variables.

To fix this, store the actual DOM node in e.g. `posName` and apply the value to the innerHTML inside the loop: `position[i].innerHTML = sumShow[k];`

I can also see no reason to use the different variables i and k. You could use i for both array. And if the inputs do not contain HTML code but only strings, you could insert them with the `textContent` attribute instead of the `innerHTML`.

```js
function summary() {

    var name = document.getElementById("commentNameA").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("commentEmailA").value;
    var card = document.getElementById("commentCardA").value;
    var posName = document.getElementById("sumName");
    var posEmail = document.getElementById("sumEmail");
    var posCard = document.getElementById("sumCard");
    
    var sumShow = [name, email, card];
    var position = [posName, posEmail, posCard];

    for(var i = 0; i < position.length; i++ ){
        position[i].textContent = sumShow[i];
    }
 }
```

```html
<form action=" " method=" ">
  <table id="order">

    <tr>
      <td id="commentName">Name:<input type="text" name="Name" id="commentNameA" class="name" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="commentEmail">Email:<input type="email" name="Email" id="commentEmailA" class="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="commentCard">Card:<input type="text" name="Card_Number" id="commentCardA" class="card" placeholder="Enter a Proxy Credit Card Number"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<div id="sumTable" class="summary">
  <table id="sumTableA" class="summaryTable" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Card Number</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="sumName"> </td>
      <td id="sumEmail"> </td>
      <td id="sumCard"> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input id="sumBtn" onclick="summary()" type="submit" name="summary" class="sumBtn" value="summary" />

</div>
```

Comment: Your a genius, thank you so much for your feedback and time... IT WORKS !!!